# FFmpeg output to textfile causing 500 Internal Server Error in PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a PHP script with two FFmpeg commands.  The first command combines a list of .ts files into a single .ts file and logs the output information into a textfile.  The second command converts the  combined .ts file into an mp4 file and logs the output information into a textfile.

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$ffmpeg = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg";
$vidClips = 'my_vids/vidClipslist.txt';
$combinedFileTs = 'my_vids/combinedFileTs.ts';
$logFileCombine = 'my_vids/logFileCombine.txt';
$logFileConvert = 'my_vids/logFileConvert.txt';
$combinedFileMp4 = 'my_vids/combinedFileMp4.mp4';

shell_exec("$ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i $vidClips -c copy $combinedFileTs 1> $logFileCombine 2>&1");

shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $combinedFileTs -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -bf 0 -codec:a mp2 -q 12 $combinedFileMp4 1> $logFileConvert 2>&1");

echo "Video finished.";
?>
```

When I run this, my 500.shtml file message is shown on the page.  However, I get no other error message echoed to the page nor are there any errors in my Cpanel error log.  I also have a php error log set up, but it doesn't show any errors.
Oddly, both of the FFmpeg commands do what they're supposed to, i.e., the "combinedFileTs.ts", "logFileCombine.txt", "combinedFileMp4.mp4", and  "logFileConvert.txt" are all created.  It's just that I'm getting the 500 error and the PHP script following the two FFmpeg commands is not being run, i.e., echo "video finished."

When I remove the output directive on the first FFmpeg command, i.e., "1> $logFileCombine 2>&1", everything works.  All the files are created, the proceeding PHP script is run, and I don't get the 500 error.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$ffmpeg = "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg";
$vidClips = 'my_vids/vidClipslist.txt';
$combinedFileTs = 'my_vids/combinedFileTs.ts';
$logFileCombine = 'my_vids/logFileCombine.txt';
$logFileConvert = 'my_vids/logFileConvert.txt';
$combinedFileMp4 = 'my_vids/combinedFileMp4.mp4';

shell_exec("$ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i $vidClips -c copy $combinedFileTs");

shell_exec("$ffmpeg -i $combinedFileTs -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -bf 0 -codec:a mp2 -q 12 $combinedFileMp4 1> $logFileConvert 2>&1");

echo "Video finished.";
?>
```

Also, the first FFmpeg command takes about 2 min to run.  Thinking that the problem was due to the PHP script being killed, I increased the max_execution_time to 600 and the memory_limit to 512M in my php.ini file but that did not fix the problem.

I need both FFmpeg commands to produce an output log textfile and I need the proceeding PHP code to run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax call returns 500 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499791/ajax-call-returns-500-error)

Comment: @smith I know, I wrote them both.  This post includes the simplified php and further explanation. I've narrowed the problem down to the "1> $logFileCombine 2>&1" on the first FFmpeg command. When I remove it, the code works.  Also, I don't think its a "timed out" issue because the command takes about 2 minutes with or without that part.  But the code without it works and the one with it doesn't.

Comment: Try to change the destnation folder permission to 777 and php to 666

Comment: @MohdAlomar I changed the destination folder to 777 but still got the 500 error.  I've also experimented with changing the permissions on the files created by the script with no success.  When you say change the php to 666, do you mean the php file above, the php.ini, or the php folder?  I'm on shared hosting, so i don't have access to the actual php folder where it resides.  Also, I get a 500 error when I change a file to 666 and an error message "SoftException in Application.cpp:254: File...is writeable by group."